# How to configure spacemacs to work correctly with haskell Stack?

Tags: spacemacs, haskell-mode

The Haskell stack build doesn't install ghc to the system, only for itself, and using spacemacs without a systemwide configured ghc have been a painful experience (to me).

My question is, there is a correct way of configuring emacs/spacemacs for using with stack, or users are supposed to install a systemwide ghc and stack to work with emacs/spacemacs and haskell?

Creating a layer specific to deal with stack seems to me to be the right  solution, but I don't know how to do this, I'm a beginner on both stack and emacs, so...

Comment: You might try settting `system-ghc: true` in your Stack `config.yaml`.

Comment: Hm, that will install ghc system wide from stack or inform stack that ghc is also installed system wide? I ask because I only have an stack ghc installed.

Comment: It tells Stack to find a globally-installed GHC.

Answer (score 1):

I use **intero** for programming Haskell in Emacs. It has superior stack support. Check it out at [its homepage](https://commercialhaskell.github.io/intero/).

Answer (score 1):

Spacemacs already have the [***Haskell layer***](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Blang/haskell).

This layer has the following dependencies:

- apply-refact (required by hlint-refactor)
- hlint (required by hlint-refactor)
- stylish-haskell (optional for haskell-mode)
- hasktags (optional)
- hoogle (optional for haskell-mode and helm-hoogle)
- ghc-mod (optional for completion)
- intero (optional for completion)

You can install them all with the following command (or the stack equivalent):

```
$ cabal install apply-refact hlint stylish-haskell hasktags hoogle
```

It also has the following syntax checkers:

- flycheck
- hlint (via flycheck)
- ghc-mod
- haskell-mode interactive

Comment: The `haskell layer` works well with a system install of haskell, but the question is how to do a good suport for the **haskell Stack**. The haskell layer doesn't do a good job on the interactive mode without having ghc installed system wide